# What is the known safety data on phenoxyethanol?

Tags: skin, health, central-nervous-system, children

I came across [this news article](https://www.nbcnews.com/health/health-news/fda-warns-mothers-about-nipple-cream-flna1c9463497) stating that a certain skincare product was declared by FDA to be unsafe for infants due to having chlorphenesin and phenoxyethanol. However, I have been unable to find any claim that phenoxyethanol contributed to any concrete harmful effect at the concentration used in that product. In particular:
  1. I could not find any actual account of harm to infants, and [FDA did not report any at that time](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-fda-cream-idUSN2330272920080526).
  2. Phenoxyethanol is widely used in many other skincare products with no reports of side effects.

I am aware that chlorphenesin affects the central nervous system, and that seems to be sufficient to explain the FDA warning not to use that product. So why did FDA mention phenoxyethanol as well? What scientific evidence were they relying on, *or* what biological effect does phenoxyethanol have on infants that can contribute to a risk of "*respiratory distress or vomiting and diarrhea in infants*" as stated by FDA?

Comment: Both of your links are to news articles, not to anything directly from the FDA.

Comment: @BryanKrause: I couldn't find the FDA statement in a form I could access, so I did the next-best.

Comment: The FDA statement on prohibied and restriced ingredients in cosmetics is [here](https://www.fda.gov/cosmetics/cosmetics-laws-regulations/prohibited-restricted-ingredients-cosmetics), and it makes clear the limited authority this body has in the US. There is a list of prohibited or restricted ingredients that does not include phenoxyethanol, so it seems strange to me that they would have made a statement about this. But I am neither a US citizen or a toxicologist. A Google search revealed that its use in the EU and Japan is restricted, and there are many articles about whether  it is toxic.

Comment: @David: Thanks for finding that! I believe that there may have been unpublished reports of adverse effects on infants of mothers using that product, and FDA decided that the most likely culprits were chlorphenesin and phenoxyethanol in combination, but the problem I have is that I can't find any data at all on how phenoxyethanol contributes to this. I too find this reported statement strange. However it's nearly impossible for both NBC and Reuters to make it up, since otherwise FDA would have easily sued them or at least issued a counter-claim.

Comment: @user21820 The health numeral of the fire diamond for 2-phenoxyethanol is a 3 (4 being the most dangerous possible categorization). The SDS from Fischer Scientific lists the LD50 (median lethal dose) in rats at 1850 mg/kg. Wikipedia mentions it is used as a preservative in pharmaceutical products, so my guess would be trace amounts of it under acute conditions would not be particularly harmful. Cyanide and Mercury salts for instance are extremely toxic but you'll still find trace amounts of them in many medications....

Comment: @user21820 That being said, if the FDA released a statement advising against administering the product to infants then my advice would be to listen to them. If the statement was restricted to infants then it suggests that an adult would need to be less cautious.

Comment: @DavidReed: Thanks for that information! My concern is that phenoxyethanol is used in many skincare products, but the FDA statement only concerns one specific product that gets ingested by infants. So I have no idea about its toxicity in other use cases including sunscreens. Where can I find the Fischer Scientific data that you cited? And do you know about toxicity for long-term daily exposure? By the way, I don't think cyanide and mercury are used in scientifically backed medicines.

Comment: @user81820 They are used in the manufacturing process as they are important reagents in organic chemistry. For instance, cyanide is used in the synthesis of ambien. It's impossible to achieve a perfect separation of reactants and products. What matters is that they are within the acceptable tolerance limits.

Comment: @DavidReed: Ok, but I don't think phenoxyethanol is merely an intermediate in these skincare products, as it is use as an active ingredient. Anyway do you have answers to the two questions I posed in my last comment? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.fishersci.com/store/msds?partNumber=AC130242500&productDescription=2-PHENOXYETHANOL%2C+99%25+250ML&vendorId=VN00032119&countryCode=US&language=en and https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31588615/

Comment: @DavidReed: Thanks for that! I think in my case (skincare products), the relevant data would be LD50 for dermal contact. I surmise that phenoxyethanol is used at less than 1% concentration in skincare products from reputable brands, and the relevant part of the JEADV article you just cited is "*the haematological effects reported in the developmental study conducted in rabbits were observed at a dose approximately 200-fold higher than that used by consumers*". Correct?